# VBA in PowerPoint : Plus Value from TextBox (ActiveXControl)

Tags: vba, powerpoint-2016

[image: All shapes from slides 1]
As so see, I wanna add the number from the UP1 textbox (The one shown "10")(ActiveXControl so it can be edited while presenting)  to the S1 Textbox (Shown "10")
Here is my code:

`Slide1.Shapes("S1").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide1.Shapes("S1").TextFrame.TextRange + UP1`

But here is my result:
[image: After Running]

Answer (score 0):

String values should be cast into numeric values before adding them.

```
With Slide1.Shapes("S1").TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = Val(.Text) + UP1
End With
```